# Google Charts API: Show/Hide Series on Legend Click. How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I found the following code online and would like to adapt it to my existing code.

Here's the **code to show/hide data series** on click I found:

http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/6gz2Q/

**Here's my Adaptation so far:**

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

      ['Draw', '1997', '1998'],
      ['1', 1236777, 1408007],
      ['2', 834427, 572882],
      ['3', 2164890, 1614181],
      ['4', 1893574, 3897171],
      ['5', 2851881, 673906],
      ['6', 359504, 630853]

    ]);


    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    // create columns array
    var columns = [];
    // display these data series by default
    var defaultSeries = [1];
    var series = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
        if (i == 0 || defaultSeries.indexOf(i) > -1) {
            // if the column is the domain column or in the default list, display the series
            columns.push(i);
        }
        else {
            // otherwise, hide it
            columns[i] = {
                label: data.getColumnLabel(i),
                type: data.getColumnType(i),
                calc: function () {
                    return null;
                }
            };
        }
        if (i > 0) {
            // set the default series option
            series[i - 1] = {};
            if (defaultSeries.indexOf(i) == -1) {
                // backup the default color (if set)
                if (typeof(series[i - 1].color) !== 'undefined') {
                    series[i - 1].backupColor = series[i - 1].color;
                }
                series[i - 1].color = '#CCCCCC';
            }
        }
    }

        // Options customize what goes inside our chart.
        var options = {

          fontName: 'verdana',
          fontSize: 12,

          // Curve the series line.
          curveType: "function",

          title: 'Title of Chart',

          // disables tooltip on hover data points
          enableInteractivity: true,

          // Enable/Disable tooltip. selection or none.
          tooltip: { trigger: 'none' },

          // Select multiple Data points.
          selectionMode: 'multiple',

          // Customize vAxis ---------------------------------------------------------
          vAxis: {

            gridlines: {color: 'black', count: 5},

            title: 'Title of vAxis',

            // Affects only the Title. eg. Not title.
            titleTextStyle: {fontName: 'verdana', fontSize: 10, color: 'black', bold: false, italic: false},

            // Range of data for vAxis eg. min: 0, max:9
            viewWindow: {min: 0, max: 5006386},

            // Affects only the Range. eg. Not title.
            textStyle: {fontName: 'verdana', fontSize: 12, color: 'black', bold: false, italic: false}
          },

          // Customize hAxis ---------------------------------------------------------
          hAxis: {

            title: 'Title of hAxis',

            // Affects only the Title. eg. Not title.
            titleTextStyle: {fontName: 'verdana', fontSize: 10, color: 'black', bold: false, italic: false},

            // Affects only the Range. eg. Not title.
            textStyle: {fontName: 'verdana', fontSize: 10, color: 'black', bold: false, italic: false}
          },

          // Customize Series ---------------------------------------------------------
          series: {
            0: {lineWidth: 1, pointSize: 4},
            1: {lineWidth: 1, pointSize: 4},
            2: {lineWidth: 1, pointSize: 4}
          },

          // Customize Annotations ---------------------------------------------------------
          annotations: {
            textStyle: {fontName: 'verdana', fontSize: 10, color: 'black', bold: false, italic: false, auraColor: 'none'}
          },

          // Custome Legends ---------------------------------------------------------
          legend: {

            // Position top, right, bottom, left.
            position: 'top',

            // Align at the star, center or end.
            alignment: 'start',

            // Affects only the Range. eg. Not title.
            textStyle: {fontName: 'verdana', fontSize: 10, color: 'black', bold: false, italic: false}
          }

        }; // End Options

    function showHideSeries () {
        var sel = chart.getSelection();
        // if selection length is 0, we deselected an element
        if (sel.length > 0) {
            // if row is undefined, we clicked on the legend
            if (sel[0].row == null) {
                var col = sel[0].column;
                if (columns[col] == col) {
                    // hide the data series
                    columns[col] = {
                        label: data.getColumnLabel(col),
                        type: data.getColumnType(col),
                        calc: function () {
                            return null;
                        }
                    };

                    // grey out the legend entry
                    series[col - 1].color = '#CCCCCC';
                }
                else {
                    // show the data series
                    columns[col] = col;
                    series[col - 1].color = null;
                }
                var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

                view.setColumns(columns);
                chart.draw(view, options);
            }
        }
    }

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', showHideSeries);

    // create a view with the default columns
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns(columns);
    chart.draw(view, options);
}

google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

**...And here is what I really wanted to figure how to incorporate into this code. I can't seem to figure it out. It's driving me nuts!**

```
// Declare our Columns and set types, roles, etc.
view.setColumns([
    0,
    1, { calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 1, type: "string", role: "annotation" },
    2, { calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 2, type: "string", role: "annotation" },
    3, { calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 3, type: "string", role: "annotation" }

]);
```

Comment: Could you post a link to the original source of your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try replacing this section:

```
if (i == 0 || defaultSeries.indexOf(i) > -1) {
    // if the column is the domain column or in the default list, display the series
    columns.push(i);
}
```

with this:

```
if (i == 0 || defaultSeries.indexOf(i) > -1) {
    // if the column is the domain column or in the default list, display the series
    columns.push(i);
    if (i > 0) {
        columns.push({
            calc: "stringify",
            sourceColumn: i,
            type: "string",
            role: "annotation"
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Although it doesn't crash, it doesn't produce the desired outcome either. Could it be because we are pushing the columns inside of a column array never really being placed inside a "view"?

Comment: I got results by changing your reply from columns.push({ to columns.push(i,{ but it posses this strange behavior e.g. it only show the annotations for the last index.

Comment: That's what I get for not testing my code.  I worked up a new example: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/6gz2Q/60/.

Comment: Excellence. Thanks a lot. Hopefully these samples help a lot of people in the future.

Answer (score 4):

**Here is asgallant solution which worked as desired.**

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'x');
    data.addColumn('number', 'y1');
    data.addColumn('number', 'y2');
    data.addColumn('number', 'y3');
    // add random data
    var y1 = 50, y2 = 50, y3 = 50;
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        y1 += Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) * Math.pow(-1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 2));
        y2 += Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) * Math.pow(-1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 2));
        y3 += Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) * Math.pow(-1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 2));
        data.addRow([i, y1, y2, y3]);
    }

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    // create columns array
    var columns = [];
    // display these data series by default
    var defaultSeries = [1, 3];
    var series = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
        if (i == 0 || defaultSeries.indexOf(i) > -1) {
            // if the column is the domain column or in the default list, display the series
            columns.push(i);
        }
        else {
            // otherwise, hide it
            columns.push({
                label: data.getColumnLabel(i),
                type: data.getColumnType(i),
                sourceColumn: i,
                calc: function () {
                    return null;
                }
            });
        }
        if (i > 0) {
            columns.push({
                calc: 'stringify',
                sourceColumn: i,
                type: 'string',
                role: 'annotation'
            });
            // set the default series option
            series[i - 1] = {};
            if (defaultSeries.indexOf(i) == -1) {
                // backup the default color (if set)
                if (typeof(series[i - 1].color) !== 'undefined') {
                    series[i - 1].backupColor = series[i - 1].color;
                }
                series[i - 1].color = '#CCCCCC';
            }
        }
    }

    var options = {
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        series: series
    }

    function showHideSeries () {
        var sel = chart.getSelection();
        // if selection length is 0, we deselected an element
        if (sel.length > 0) {
            // if row is undefined, we clicked on the legend
            if (sel[0].row == null) {
                var col = sel[0].column;
                if (typeof(columns[col]) == 'number') {
                    var src = columns[col];

                    // hide the data series
                    columns[col] = {
                        label: data.getColumnLabel(src),
                        type: data.getColumnType(src),
                        sourceColumn: src,
                        calc: function () {
                            return null;
                        }
                    };

                    // grey out the legend entry
                    series[src - 1].color = '#CCCCCC';
                }
                else {
                    var src = columns[col].sourceColumn;

                    // show the data series
                    columns[col] = src;
                    series[src - 1].color = null;
                }
                var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
                view.setColumns(columns);
                chart.draw(view, options);
            }
        }
    }

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', showHideSeries);

    // create a view with the default columns
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns(columns);
    chart.draw(view, options);
}

google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```