# toggling series of google chart on and off by clicking on legend

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api, google-visualization

I have an area chart that has 6 series. I want the user to be able to click on the legend to toggle the visibility of a series.

I found [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/6gz2Q/) & have tried including it in my code below but nothing happens. Before adding this code if I clicked on one of the series in the legend the series would become thicker, then click on it again & it would go back to normal, believe this is some default behaviour. However with this code included once the series gets thicker I can't do anything, i.e. zoom or click on the chart to get the value of a point.

Not sure what I am missing?

**Update**

I have also tried following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777344/google-charts-api-show-hide-series-on-legend-click-how) but same result.

**latest update**

I have changed my code to the following.

The error I'm getting now is the following...

*Uncaught Error: Invalid column index 8. Should be an integer in the range [0-7].
    at gvjs_en (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:75)
    at gvjs_P.gvjs_.uc (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:92)
    at gvjs_P.gvjs_.Za (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:91)
    at Data.displayed.reduce (jScore.js:220)
    at Array.reduce ()
    at vparse (jScore.js:214)
    at showHideSeries (jScore.js:202)
    at gvjs_Zn. (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:179)
    at gvjs__n (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:129)
    at gvjs_Zn.gvjs_.dispatchEvent (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:127)*

My HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jScore.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart', 'table'] });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="chartScore" style="height:1000px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My JS file

```
var MyData = {};

$(document).ready(function () {

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'api/Score',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        MyData.dataValues = data;
        PopulateData();
        DrawChartScores();
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error loading data! Please try again");
    }
});

};


var Data = {};

function PopulateData() {

Data = {
    displayed: [...MyData.dataValues],
    hidden: Object.keys(MyData.dataValues[0]).reduce((a, c) => {
        a[c] = false;
        return a;
    }, {}),
    map: Object.keys(MyData.dataValues[0])
};
}

function DrawChartScores() {

 var dataValues = MyData.dataValues;
 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
 var options = {
    title: 'Scores', width: '80%', height: '80%',
    explorer:
        {
            keepInBounds: true,
            actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset']
        },
    series: Data.map.reduce((a, c, i) => {
        a[i] = {};
        return a;
    }, {})
  };

data.addColumn('date', 'Day');
data.addColumn('number', 'A');
data.addColumn('number', 'B');
data.addColumn('number', 'C');
data.addColumn('number', 'D');
data.addColumn('number', 'E');
data.addColumn('number', 'F');
data.addColumn('number', 'Nrs');

// add data
for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
    data.addRow([new Date(dataValues[i].DateRet), dataValues[i].A, dataValues[i].B, dataValues[i].C,
        dataValues[i].D, dataValues[i].E, dataValues[i].F, dataValues[i].Nrs]);
}

var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chartScore'));
var last = {
    column: true,
    row: true
  };

 function showHideSeries() {
    var sel = chart.getSelection();

    if (sel.length === 0 && last.row === null) {
        Data.hidden[Data.map[last.column]] = !Data.hidden[Data.map[last.column]];
    } else if (sel.length && sel[0].row === null) {
        // toggle the current item selected
        Data.hidden[Data.map[sel[0].column]] = !Data.hidden[Data.map[sel[0].column]];
        last = sel[0];
    } else {
        return;
    }

    vparse(data);
    options = vkillLegend(options);
    chart.draw(data, options);

   };

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', showHideSeries);
chart.draw(data, options);

};

function vparse(data) {
 Data.displayed.reduce((a, c, i) => {
    for (let k in c) {
        if (k === "DateRet") continue;
        if (Data.hidden[k])
            data.setValue(i, Data.map.indexOf(k), null);
        else
            data.setValue(i, Data.map.indexOf(k), c[k]);
    }
    return true;
}, []);
return data;
}

function vkillLegend(options) {
 options.series = Object.keys(options.series).reduce((a, c, i) => {
    let current = {};
    if (Data.hidden[Data.map[i]]) current.color = "#CCCCCC";
    else c.color = null;
    a[i - 1] = current;
    return a;
}, {});
return options;
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Explanation at the bottom, here is the working code:

```js
// jshint esnext: true
google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart', 'table']});


var dataValues = [{DateScore: '2018-6-14', A: 1000, B: 900, C: 800, D: 700, E: 600, F: 500, NrS: 400, }, {DateScore: '2018-6-15', A: 1000, B: 900, C: 800, D: 700, E: 600, F: 500, NrS: 400, }, {DateScore: '2018-6-17', A: 1000, B: 900, C: 800, D: 700, E: 600, F: 500, NrS: 400, }, {DateScore: '2018-6-22', A: 800, B: 600, C: 1000, D: 900, E: 300, F: 100, NrS: 600, } ];

var Data = {
    displayed: [...dataValues],
    hidden: Object.keys(dataValues[0]).reduce((a, c) => {
        a[c] = false;
        return a;
    }, {}),
    map: Object.keys(dataValues[0])
};


google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(DrawChartScores);

function DrawChartScores() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    var options = {
        title: 'Scores',
        width: '80%',
        height: '80%',
        explorer: {
            keepInBounds: true,
            actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset']
        },
        series: Data.map.reduce((a, c, i) => {
            a[i] = {};
            return a;
        }, {})
    };

    data.addColumn('date', 'Day');
    data.addColumn('number', 'A');
    data.addColumn('number', 'B');
    data.addColumn('number', 'C');
    data.addColumn('number', 'D');
    data.addColumn('number', 'E');
    data.addColumn('number', 'F');
    data.addColumn('number', 'NrS');

    for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
        let newRow = Object.values(dataValues[i]);
        newRow[0] = new Date(newRow[0]);
        data.addRow(newRow);
    }

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chartP'));
    var last = {
        column: true,
        row: true
    };


    function showHideSeries() {
        var sel = chart.getSelection();

        if (sel.length === 0 && last.row === null) {
            Data.hidden[Data.map[last.column]] = !Data.hidden[Data.map[last.column]];
        } else if (sel.length && sel[0].row === null) {
            // toggle the current item selected
            Data.hidden[Data.map[sel[0].column]] = !Data.hidden[Data.map[sel[0].column]];
            last = sel[0];
        } else {
            return;
        }

        vparse(data);
        options = vkillLegend(options);
        chart.draw(data, options);

    }

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', showHideSeries);
    chart.draw(data, options);

}

function vparse(data) {
    Data.displayed.reduce((a, c, i) => {
        for (let k in c) {
            if (k === "DateScore") continue;
            if (Data.hidden[k])
                data.setValue(i, Data.map.indexOf(k), null);
            else
                data.setValue(i, Data.map.indexOf(k), c[k]);
        }
        return true;
    }, []);
    return data;
}

function vkillLegend(options) {
    options.series = Object.keys(options.series).reduce((a, c, i) => {
        let current = {};
        if (Data.hidden[Data.map[i]]) current.color = "#CCCCCC";
        else c.color = null;
        a[i - 1] = current;
        return a;
    }, {});
    return options;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>My Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="chartP" style="height:1000px"></div>
</body>
```

### Explanation

#### Variables

- **`Data`** object:

  - **`displayed`** - array that contains all the starting data provided by `dataValues`
  - **`hidden`** - keeps track of the legend items that have been hidden with a simple object mapping the column key to the boolean representation of their display
  - **`map`** - simply an array where the index of the item is the location on the chart, also used to convert column index to column key
- **`options.series`** - an object representation of each of the columns; this is used to modify the legend color when clicked.
- **`last`** - this is more-so a product of google charts event handling; essentially, if you click on the same thing twice, the second click will register with no data from `getSelection()`. This means we have to store all the previous clicks if we want a user-friendly experience. Otherwise, the user would have to click somewhere else on the chart before clicking back on the legend item.

---

#### Functions

When the legend item is clicked, there are a few things that happens:

1. **`showHideSeries()`** decides whether or not the click was on the legend, and if it was on the legend, act accordingly - regardless of the selection being empty or not;
2. **`vparse()`** prepares the new data set based on the base data provided in `dataValues`
3. **`vkillLegend()`** kills the styling on the legend items which are no longer present in the data set, and restores styling for data that was re-added;
4. Finally, we are ready to push all the changes to the chart, and we can do that by using [`chart.draw()`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#visdraw)

You can see a working example by clicking the **`Run code snippet`** button above.

***I hope this helps!***

Comment: thanks for your answer its brilliant. I have updated my code in my post but still having problems which is more due to my lack of knowledge and first time of doing this rather than your explanation. I'm not sure I'm using var Data = { displayed... correctly in my example?

Comment: Sorry hadn't saved my changes but have now

Comment: Where does var  Data get populated? I assume I shouldn't have it in the $(document).ready function? But if it is not here I'm not sure how it gets populated?

Comment: You should probably re-populate it within the ajax callback

Comment: Thanks actually just did that. Getting an invalid column index error so think I'm getting closer

Comment: No problem! I just saw your replies. I wonder who downvoted and why they didn't leave feedback

Comment: yeh bit annoying when they don't give any feedback as to why they down voted as its not very helpful